# Can't change the background of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to change the background of the body. Im thinking about cover the background of the webpage with 5 different images, each image cover one section (# of page1,page2, page3,page4 and page5).

But now when im trying the image isnt showing.

I have tried with one image so far and I have tried to make it background-image of body. I have tried making a div-rule with that particular background. I have tried two different images. But nothing seems to change the background.

I have declared background-color and that way the background changes but images does not seems to work.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjcwfey3/

```
<p>Seems I needed this to link jfiddle.</p>
```

Please help me locate the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the issue is - http://jsfiddle.net/xjcwfey3/1/

Comment: Try to add a background image in any possible way.

Comment: Off course on the fiddel doesn't work .. you refer to an image on a relative path ... http://jsfiddle.net/xjcwfey3/2/

Comment: @Mello Clearly a bg image is possible - http://jsfiddle.net/xjcwfey3/1/

Comment: @Danko I did not add any b-image. I deleted my tries to add the b-ground image since it did not work. My dreamweaver shows a background though when Im running it on local the image is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: There is your problem, dreamweaver! No but seriously this will be a path problem. The image path needs to be correct, to reference the image trying to be shown.

Comment: just to have mentioned it - you use two different jquery versions there ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your:

```
background-image:url(images/Animation_background.jpg);
```

To:

```
background-image:url(http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/511/991/3a5.jpg);
```

Seems to work good, which means that you probably don't have access to images/Animation_background.jpg.

1) Check the URL of your image, make sure the image loads by itself in the browser.
2) Fix the path to the image based on your css file (you might have to prepend a / in the image path)

Comment: I have retyped the searchway a couple of times. And dreamweaver is helping me targeting the image. Still the background image does not load.

Comment: I just edited the security to give all users permission to use the map. Did not change much. THough your link solution worked fine! So I will go with it:)

Answer (score 1):

put big image

```css
*
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
 


#wrap {
 
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 
}

body

{

  background:url(http://demo2.woothemes.com/memorable/files/2013/05/thai-food-580x352.jpg) no-repeat; 


}


#menu

{
 background-color:black;
 width:100%;
 position: fixed;
 opacity:1;
 
 }
 
 #menu ul

{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
 }
#menu a {
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
 display:block;
 float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-decoration: none;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:1%;
 padding-bottom:1%;

   
 
 }
 #menu a:hover
 {
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 }
 
 li {
    display: inline;
}

#page1 {
 
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:5%;
 padding-bottom:3%;
 padding-right:10%;
 padding-left:10%;
 margin-bottom:5%;
 margin-left:15%;
 border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);

 }
 
 #page2 {
 
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
 padding-bottom:3%;
 padding-top:3%;
 padding-right:10%;
 padding-left:10%;
  margin-bottom:5%;
   margin-left:15%;

border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
 }
 
 #page3 {
 
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
 padding-bottom:3%;
 padding-top:3%;
 padding-right:10%;
 padding-left:10%;
  margin-bottom:5%;
   margin-left:15%;

border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
 }
 
 #page4 {
 
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
 padding-bottom:3%;
 padding-top:3%;
 padding-right:10%;
 padding-left:10%;
   margin-bottom:5%;
 margin-left:15%;

  marginborder-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
border: 0px solid #000000;-bottom:5%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);

 }
 
 #page5 {
 
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
 padding-bottom:3%;
 padding-top:3%;
 padding-right:10%;
 padding-left:10%;
  margin-bottom:5%;
   margin-left:15%;

border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 59px 20px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
box-shadow: 6px 7px 5px 8px rgba(128,123,128,0.54);
 }
 
 p {
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;}
```

```html
<!-- http://localhost/portfolio/index.php  -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Portfolio</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Menyn -->
<div id="menu">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#random">Random</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div id="wrap">

<!-- Hemsidan i sin helhet-->
<div id="page1">
  <a id="about"></a>
  <h3> First Part</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada, dolor a sagittis placerat, nisi sem porttitor orci, 
non rutrum velit velit sed enim. Aliquam imperdiet, quam ac maximus suscipit, mauris lorem volutpat dui, quis imperdiet leo dolor a nunc.
 Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quis sodales tortor. Sed porta nisl sed massa ullamcorper, a porttitor justo malesuada. Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quiCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qu</div>

<div id="page2">
  <a id="portfolio"></a>
  <h3> Second Part</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada, dolor a sagittis placerat, nisi sem porttitor orci, 
non rutrum velit velit sed enim. Aliquam imperdiet, quam ac maximus suscipit, mauris lorem volutpat dui, quis imperdiet leo dolor a nunc.
 Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quis sodales tortor. Sed porta nisl sed massa ullamcorper, a porttitor justo malesuada. Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui</div>

<div id="page3">
  <a id="contact"></a>
  <h3> Third Part</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada, dolor a sagittis placerat, nisi sem porttitor orci, 
non rutrum velit velit sed enim. Aliquam imperdiet, quam ac maximus suscipit, mauris lorem volutpat dui, quis imperdiet leo dolor a nunc.
 Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quis sodales tortor. Sed porta nisl sed massa ullamcorper, a porttitor justo malesuada. Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quiCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qu</div>

<div id="page4">
  <a id="home"></a>
  <h3> Forth Part</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada, dolor a sagittis placerat, nisi sem porttitor orci, 
non rutrum velit velit sed enim. Aliquam imperdiet, quam ac maximus suscipit, mauris lorem volutpat dui, quis imperdiet leo dolor a nunc.
 Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quis sodales tortor. Sed porta nisl sed massa ullamcorper, a porttitor justo malesuada. Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui</div>

<div id="page5">
  <a id="random"></a>
  <h3> Fifth Part</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin malesuada, dolor a sagittis placerat, nisi sem porttitor orci, 
non rutrum velit velit sed enim. Aliquam imperdiet, quam ac maximus suscipit, mauris lorem volutpat dui, quis imperdiet leo dolor a nunc.
 Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quis sodales tortor. Sed porta nisl sed massa ullamcorper, a porttitor justo malesuada. Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quiCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec quCurabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qui Nunc pulvinar eu massa
 aliquam tincidunt. Cras tincidunt dolor sagittis laoreet posuere. 
 Fusce id bibendum libero. Vestibulum auctor nulla dolor, sit amet sollicitudin sem varius in. Aenean ullamcorper mauris in magna luctus, ac fringilla massa tincidunt. 
 Cras vitae eros diam. Vestibulum viverra aliquam mi, vel tempus mauris luctus id. Curabitur convallis lobortis ipsum facilisis fringilla. Pellentesque vel nibh augue. 
 Vestibulum gravida, felis nec efficitur tempus,
  odio diam feugiat risus, ac molestie nulla lorem vel tellus. 
Donec qu</div>
</div><!-- DIV WRAP END -->

<!-- Koder längst ner för en enkelt övergång animation när man klickar länk -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".contactLink").click(function(){
                    if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
                        $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
                    }
                });
            });
            function closeForm(){
                $("#messageSent").show("slow");
                setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
           }

$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
         $(this).click(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
           var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.style.height = "101%";
        d.style.overflow = "hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        window.scrollTo(0,scrollToM);
        setTimeout(function() {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
            }, 10);
           return false;
         });
      }
    }
  });
});

</script>
<!-- Menu fade -->


<script type="text/javascript">

       var $menu = $("#menu");
    var opacity = $menu.css("opacity");
    var scrollStopped;

    var fadeInCallback = function () {
        if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(scrollStopped);
        }

        scrollStopped = setTimeout(function () {
            $menu.animate({ opacity: 1 }, "slow");
        }, 1000);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (!$menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) {
            $menu.animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow", fadeInCallback);
        } else {
            fadeInCallback.call(this);
        }
    });
</script>

<script>
tiles = $("#page5, #page2, #page3, #page4").fadeTo(0, 0);

$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(1000,1);
    });
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why?  what's a problem?